# Bibtex stretches the first line

Tags: line-breaking, urls

The first line looks very "stretched". How can I improve the formating?

[image]

```
@misc{Rel1,
author = {J. Citizen}, 
title = {Kinect used as Topshop dressing room},
month = {may},
year = {2011},
howpublished = {http://www.playerattack.com/news/2011/05/10/kinect-used-as-topshop-dressing-room/} 
}
```

**Edit:**
`\url{}` does not solve the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest possible solution is to put `\allowbreak` in appropriate place/places in the web address in your `.bib` file:

```
@misc{Rel1,
author = {J. Citizen}, 
title = {Kinect used as Topshop dressing room},
month = {may},
year = {2011},
howpublished = {http://www.\allowbreak{}playerattack.com/news/2011/05/10/kinect-used-as-topshop-dressing-room/} 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use:

```
@misc{Rel1,
author = {J. Citizen}, 
title = {Kinect used as Topshop dressing room},
month = {may},
year = {2011},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.playerattack.com/news/2011/05/10/kinect-used-as-topshop-dressing-room/}} 
}
```

and in your main document

```
\usepackage{url}
```

if not already present.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the URL isn't breaking at / or . , probably you need to modify your bst file (or switch to an updated one) that puts a command such as `\url...}` around the URL in the generated LaTeX, and then use a package such as `url` (or `hyperref` if I remember correctly) that typesets URLs in a way that allows line breaking at more points.

Alternatively get latex to typeset the bibliography ragged right.